# IE / ME - Vertical align middle button text with flex using Boostrap 4

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, flexbox, bootstrap-4, microsoft-edge

The text in the button should be on the center, but it's displayed at the top using internet explorer, what's wrong?

```css
button {
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <button class="w-100 f-default-f btn btn-primary d-flex justify-content-between px-3">
    <div>Text</div>
    <div>icon</div>
  </button>
</div>
```

I add a codepen with Boostrap 4 alpha with the code:

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/PaqLNm

It works well with Mozilla Firefox and Chrome, with Microsoft Edge or Internet explorer doesn't have the desired behavior.

Comment: Does it behave as expected in other web browsers? What version of IE are you using?

Comment: @Dragonthoughts IE v11, it works well in Chrome + Mozilla. Tested now on ME and doesn't work too.

Comment: Works as intended for me in IE v11.48.17134 as well as Edge v42.17134

Comment: Tested in IE 11.332 and its not working.

Comment: A mi no me preguntas, solo soy una chica jijiji @Troyer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to add class `align-items-center` to `button` element, which will aligns child elements vertically center.

> Note: Tested on Edge, IE11, IE10 browser it works fine with this fix

Check demo [**here**](https://codepen.io/jpI/pen/XYdeVM?editors=1100)

HTML

```
<div class="container">
  <button class="w-100 f-default-f btn btn-primary d-flex align-items-center justify-content-between px-3">
    <div>Text</div>
    <div>icon</div>
  </button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You are using flex, and flex have only partial-support on IE11 duo to large amount of bugs.

[image: Compatibility table]

For example, IE 10-11 always assume a `content` box model when using `flex-basis` to determine a flex item's size, even if that item is set to `box-sizing: border-box`.

Other known bug's:

-IE 11 requires a unit to be added to the third argument, the `flex-basis` property ([more info](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex-basis))

-In IE10 and IE11, containers with `display: flex` and `flex-direction: column` will not properly calculate their flexed childrens' sizes if the container has `min-height` but no explicit `height` property.

-IE 11 does not vertically align items correctly when `min-height` is used

Sources:
https://github.com/philipwalton/flexbugs#7-flex-basis-doesnt-account-for-box-sizingborder-box
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex-basis
https://caniuse.com/#search=flex

Comment: And where is the solution?

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a `lineheight` property in one of your CSS files?

Try adding this value or chagging it, it will align your text in the button for IE (and surely for Edge too).

Comment: The height is not fixed, without line-height it should be vertically centered, like on Firefox and Chrome.